# Does medication make the body dependent?

Tags: human-biology, pharmacology, medicinal-chemistry

First of, I know of course that certain medication can cause an addiction if incorrectly used. But as far as I understand it, drugs prone to cause addiction have some agent in it, that makes them addictive.

What I am interested in is a bit different though: If a drug "helps your body" do something your body can not or only insufficiently do alone, does it get dependent on this drug, **even if the drug does not have addictive substances in it**?

Or in other words: **Can the human body unlearn something because of the fact that medication helped it do it for some time?**

Edit: To make the question a little more clear, I can give the following example: I recently received medication containing **Etilefrine**, which contracts my blood vessels and thus prevents me from fainting in certain situations. **If I take this medication regularly for a year and the suddenly stop it, could it be possible, that my blood vessels "forgot" how to contract on their own?**

Comment: Stopping drugs/alcohol "cold turkey" *can* be fatal - drug dependency is a common problem

Comment: @rg255 I checked the Wikipedia article on it, along with the one on [Drug withdrawal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drug_withdrawal) and it had some useful information in it. However, the articles tend to discuss drugs containing addictive substances. I would also be interested in drugs without those substances.

Comment: You have now specified your question, but a different thing you might be interested in is steroid withdrawal and what can happen if corticosteroids are stopped abruptly.

Comment: @YviDe I gave steroid withdrawal a look, it is a very interesting subject and roughly the thing I asked about. Thank you!